# Remove default spring boot welcome page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot restful application but if I go to  the following URLS:

```
http://localhost:8080

http://localhost:8080/profile
```

I then see some default spring boot JSON like the following:

```
{


  "_links" : {


    "customerEntities" : {

    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/customerEntities{?page,size,sort}",
    "templated" : true
   },
  "profile" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
   }
 }
}
```

how can I disable this? I dont want those pages apearing

Comment: Do you have a dependency to `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`? If so, this dependency provides these responses. You can remove the dependency to remove those kind of responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because  Spring HATEOAS and Spring Data JPA and combines them together automatically.

This dependency make these changes

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

so check this need for your your project or remove the dependency and check

[More](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)