# Setting up REST api with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I'm just trying to set up a simple rest api with spring, and when going to http://localhost:8080/ I get some JSON-response that I have not defined:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the REST controller:

```
package com.okta.developer.demo.beer;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
public class BeerController {
    private BeerRepository repository;

    public BeerController(BeerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }

    @GetMapping("/good-beers")
    public Collection<Beer> goodBeers() {
        return repository.findAll().stream()
              .filter(this::isGreat)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private boolean isGreat(Beer beer) {
        return !beer.getName().equals("Budweiser") &&
              !beer.getName().equals("Coors Light") &&
              !beer.getName().equals("PBR");
    }
}
```

So, basically I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help, and just tell me if there might be some important information missing, that is needed to solve the problem!

EDIT:

A part of the console output produced by maven is the following:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
```

I don't know if the *Attaching agents* is a part of the problem either.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951284/remove-default-spring-boot-welcome-page

Comment: It appears that you have a `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` dependency in your project, it provides the default responses

Comment: @AndreiKovrov tried to do that earlier, but the dependency mentioned in that post import the RepositoryRestResource annotation...

Comment: And the paths defined in the `BeerController` class are not available.

Comment: Use `RepositoryRestResource` only if you want to create `Hypermedia-Driven RESTful Web Service`  https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/

Comment: It sounds like you want a simple REST API, so.. don't use `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`

Comment: Btw, got the problem when trying to follow the tutorial in this post https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/06/bootiful-development-with-spring-boot-and-react

Answer (score 0):

In your project 2 Controllers are dealing with path "/".
One Controller is your BeerController, the other one is inside a dependency you import with Gradle or Maven.
Here are the Dependencies named (spring-boot-starter-data-rest), which cause this trouble:
[Remove default spring boot welcome page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951284/remove-default-spring-boot-welcome-page)

After removing the dependency your BeerController should work, if you still have some other Spring Web dependency like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Another option would be to use another path in your @GetMapping of test method, e.g. @GetMapping("/test"). Then you have to call http://localhost:8080/test

In my German blog is an article about how to build Controllers with Spring-Boot:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/10/rest-json-apis-in-java-leicht-gemacht.html